# Append function doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, append

I don't know why this  code isn't working on IE:

```
storyEl.append(storyImageEl);
storyEl.append(storyTitleEl);
storyEl.append(storyAuthorEl);
storyEl.append(storyContentEl);
storyContainer.append(storyEl);
return storyContainer;
storyEl.append(shareButton);
```

I am not sure if they are the issues, but essentially on my page: http://soulrelicsmuseum.me/Stories.html. These are completely not showing on IE. 
Would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction.
I tried adding var on before storyE1 but didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, it's important to include all the code necessary to understand the problem, and to include it *here* in the question and not just via a link to some off-site resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869419/jquery-append-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: In any case it doesn't make much sense under any circumstances to have code following a `return` statement.

Comment: @RyanTuosto: Why do you think that's a duplicate?

Comment: Could be a cross browser issue, different browsers use different JS syntaxes, a major headache before libraries like jQuery came out, You can also look at MooTools whose syntax is more like traditional JS but takes care of compatibility issues as well.

Comment: @inarilo: Browser compatibility is really very good today. Using libraries for compatibility is mostly overkill. And the OP is already using jQuery.

Comment: Well if it's not working only on IE my first guess will still be browser incompatibility. In any case, the page includes jQuery but then does not use it for this code.

Comment: @inarilo: Makes more sense to polyfill new features that aren't yet implemented in some browsers. Limiting yourself with unnecessary abstractions seems like an unfortunate approach.

Comment: @Van try using `new Array` to declare your array. As I recall this was an issue in IE even two decades ago. Or just use jQuery throughout.

Comment: @squint I suppose MooTools does exactly that.

Comment: Are you meaning to use appendChild instead of append?  I noticed that you use removeChild in your js code but not appendChild, I think that's your mistake.

Comment: @James thanks yesss you are right!!! thanks!!! have been super confused with javascript and jquery it's now fixed!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your `arrangeStories();` in jquery.ready. When your code is ready to run, DOM is still not ready.

```
$(function(){
  arrangeStories();
})
```